# How to disable caching in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I am caching my data in redis using spring caching abstraction.
Is there any way to disable caching through application.properties file.
I tried using `spring.cache.type=none`, but it didn't worked.

I know if I remove `@EnableCaching`, it will disable caching,  but is there any other way to do this without changing the code

Comment: Check this out https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html, spring.cache.type=none should work for a particular environment at least

Answer (score -1):

Try to put following variable in your properties file:

```
rediscache=disable
```

Hope it will help.